# Multiple questions about light in the bible

Tags: genesis

I only just recently started studying other religons, I'll explain my question more.

In Genesis 1:3 "And God said, Let there be light: and there was light." My question is what is this light and where does it come from, since the sun was created a couple of days afterwards, and the sun as we know it provides us with light. and that question leads me into another thought, I have seen on a bible forum that the light mentioned in Genesis 1:3 is what provided the vegetation that was created on the third day (mentioned in Genesis 1:11) since the sun wasn't around until the fourth day... To wrap this all up, I'll list my question in points.

1. Is the light that was created on the first day the same as the light that the sun provides?
2. Is that light still providing the earth with light?
3. Does that light have a source? And what is that source?

I hope I can get a clear and satisfying answers, thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  When you have a moment, please take our Tour to find out how we are different to other sites and what we look for in good questions: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the “Light” of Genesis 1:3?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/what-is-the-light-of-genesis-13)

Answer (score 0):

> Genesis 1:3 And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light.

This light is photon or electromagnetic radiation. 3 days later God made the sun and moon.

> Genesis 1:16
> God made two great lights--the greater light to govern the day and the lesser light to govern the night. He also made the stars.

Is the light that was created on the first day the same as the light that the sun provides?

No.

Is that light still providing the earth with light?

Not in the sense of visible light.

> 14 And God said, “Let there be lights in the vault of the sky to separate the day from the night, and let them serve as signs to mark sacred times, and days and years, 15and let them be lights in the vault of the sky to give **light on the earth**.” And it was so.

The sun and the moon give visible light to the earth.

Does that light have a source? And what is that source?

God spoke it. God is the source.

Revelation 22:5 shows that God will dispense with the sunlight in the future:

> There will be no more night. They will not need the light of a lamp or the light of the sun, for the Lord God will give them light. And they will reign for ever and ever.

Comment: You have not substantiated your primary statement _This light is photon or electromagnetic radiation._. This is an assertion of opinion.

Comment: What is the difference between the light that was created on the first day and the light that the sun provides? Since both are "light"

Comment: Exactly, therefore by definition, photon == light.

Answer (score 0):

Ozzie's answer in [What is the “Light” of Genesis 1:3?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/what-is-the-light-of-genesis-13/43466#43466) resolves this question.

Summary:

- The sun, stars, etc. were created in the beginning.
- On the first day, the clouds that enshrouded the Earth were made thin enough to allow lightness and darkness.
- By the fourth day, the clouds were dispersed enough to allow direct sunlight to reach the surface.

In Genesis 1:16 ("God *made* two great lights"), the Hebrew word that is translated as "made" in English does not mean to create, it means to complete something that already exists.

For details of the different verbs used in the original Hebrew, see:
[Genesis 1:3, Did God Make Light?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54383/genesis-13-did-god-make-light/54395#54395).

The quick answers to your questions are: it *was* sunlight, the sun *is* still shining today, and the source of its light is hydrogen fusion.